# Testing ember nested routes fails

Tags: testing, ember.js, qunit, karma-runner

I'm using karma with qUnit (after following [this tutorial](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/07/21/Integration-testing-your-emberjs-app-with-QUnit-and-Karma/)) to test my Ember application. It's mostly going well, however I've run into a problem that doesn't make sense.

Given the 2 following tests:

```
test('can get to products', function() {
  visit('/products/')
    .then(function() {
      ok(find('*'));
    });
});


test('can get to catalogues', function() {
  visit('/products/catalogues')
    .then(function() {
      ok(find('*'));
    });
});
```

The first will run fine. The test runner gets to `/products` and finds something.

However, **the second test returns an error in the console:**

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun. You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an Ember.run
```

I turned on transition logs, and the test runner is visiting `products.catalogues.index` before throwing the error.

Any ideas with this? Or is it simply a bug inside ember's testing tools?

Both are valid routes defined inside the router...

Comment: What is the version of emberjs?

Comment: RC7 unfortunately... I need to update to 1.0.0 but there's a lot of breaking changes/deprecation warnings...

Comment: If you see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/pG7Rv/, there isn't need to use Ember.run. But I think that your version will need. Not sure.

Comment: I found the complete source of the tutorial https://github.com/toranb/ember-testing-example/blob/master/js/tests/integration_tests.js, maybe can help.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the error holds the key to how to fix this problem. You have to make sure that any code that make async calls is wrapped in Ember.run. This includes things as simple as the create and set methods.

If you have something like

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [
            Ember.Object.create({title: "product1"}),
            Ember.Object.create({title: "product2"})
        ]
    }
});
```

**refactor it to**

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [
            Ember.run( Ember.Object, "create", {title: "product1"} ),
            Ember.run( Ember.Object, "create", {title: "product2"} )
        ]
    }
});
```

**or**

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.run(function() {
            return [
            Ember.Object.create({title: "product1"}),
            Ember.Object.create({title: "product2"})
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

If you posted your **/products** code it would be easier to give a more specific answer.

Comment: So I have to refactor my *actual* codebase to use Ember.run whenever I do anything async, just so it works for testing?

Comment: You were right - it's the model hook inside `App.CataloguesRoute` that was causing the error. However it's just a simple bit of ember-data code, using `App.Catalogue.find();` It still errors out and I'm unable to load the page :(

Comment: Unless the Ember router has gotten smarter recently, returning the result of `Ember.run` isn't a general solution. Specifically, if you want `model` to return a promise to delay transition, `Ember.run` will hide that promise from the router.